# Call a method once all deferred completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have this class:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var FileRead = function() {
    this.init();
};


p.read = function(file) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    fileReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();

};

lx.FileRead = FileRead;
}(window));
```

The class is called in a loop:

```
var self = this;
    $.each(files, function(index, file){
        self.fileRead.read(file).done(function(fileB64){self.fileShow(file, fileB64, fileTemplate);});

    });
```

My question is, is there a way to call a method once the loop has completed and `self.fileRead` has returned it's deferred for everything in the loop?

I want it to call the method even if one or more of the deferred fails.

Comment: Isn't that what `.always()` is for?

Comment: You should use a better promise library.

Comment: Does `.read` use any methods internally on the object? Is there any reason it's an instance method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.when lets you wrap up multiple promises into one.  Other promise libraries have something similar.  Build up an array of promises returned by fileRead.read and then pass that array to $.when and hook up then/done/fail/always methods to the promise returned by .when

```
    // use map instead of each and put that inside a $.when call
    $.when.apply(null, $.map(files, function(index, file){
        // return the resulting promise
        return self.fileRead.read(file).done(function(fileB64){self.fileShow(file, fileB64, fileTemplate);});

    }).done(function() {  

      //now everything is done 
    })
```

Comment: there are examples in the docs and googling will find you more now that you know the name of the api to use  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - agreed. I further commented in an answer below

Comment: Why is this answer accepted when it doesn't address the requirement, "to call the method even if one or more of the deferred fails."?

Answer (score 0):

```
var self = this;
var processFiles = function (data) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(files, function (index, file) {
        var def = data.fileRead.read(file);
        promises.push(def);
    });
    return $.when.apply(undefined, promises).promise();
}

self.processFiles(self).done(function(results){ 
    //do stuff
});
```

`$.when` says "when all these promises are resolved... do something". It takes an infinite (variable) number of parameters. In this case, you have an array of promises;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is closed but as the doc states for `$.when`: In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when **immediately** fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. (emphasis on immediately is mine)

If you want to complete **all** Deferreds even when one fails, I believe you need to come up with your own plugin along those lines below. The `$.whenComplete` function expects an array of **functions** that return a `JQueryPromise`.

```
    var whenComplete = function (promiseFns) {
        var me = this;
        return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
            if (promiseFns.length === 0) {
                dfd.resolve([]);
            } else {
                var numPromises = promiseFns.length;
                var failed = false;
                var args;
                var resolves = [];

                promiseFns.forEach(function (promiseFn) {
                    try  {
                        promiseFn().fail(function () {
                            failed = true;
                            args = arguments;
                        }).done(function () {
                            resolves.push(arguments);
                        }).always(function () {
                            if (--numPromises === 0) {
                                if (failed) {
                                    //Reject with the last error
                                    dfd.reject.apply(me, args);
                                } else {
                                    dfd.resolve(resolves);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        var msg = 'Unexpected error processing promise. ' + e.message;
                        console.error('APP> ' + msg, promiseFn);
                        dfd.reject.call(me, msg, promiseFn);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).promise();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the requirement, "to call the method even if one or more of the deferred fails" you ideally want an `.allSettled()` method but jQuery doesn't have that particular grain of sugar, so you have to do a DIY job :

You could find/write a `$.allSettled()` utility or achieve the same effect with a combination of `.when()` and `.then()` as follows :

```
var self = this;
$.when.apply(null, $.map(files, function(index, file) {
    return self.fileRead.read(file).then(function(fileB64) {
        self.fileShow(file, fileB64, fileTemplate);
        return fileB64;//or similar
    }, function() {
        return $.when();//or similar
    });
})).done(myMethod);
```

If it existed, `$.allSettled()` would do something similar internally.

Next, "in myMethod, how to distinguish the good responses from the errors?", but that's another question :)